# How to move documents and list items in Windows SharePoint Services?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to provide users with an easy way to move documents and lists items in WSS 3.0. They want to be able to move across lists, sites and site collections without loss of version history, metadata, and author/date info. This functionality is unfortunately not available OOB. Anyone know a good solution/product?

Answer (score 1):

None of the products out there can do it and even if they do, all of them would modify the dates and the by's (modified by). We developed a custom solution to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we also ended up developing a custom solution to meet the requirements of the customer. It turned out pretty good and we decided to make a small product out of it. For those interested a free version is now available @ [www.sharepointproducts.com](http://www.sharepointproducts.com) 
However, the full version is not free.